# CountDownTimer value not accurate in android app

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I am trying to implement 50sec timer in my app. I used following code. But somehow time is not being decremented well.
values are printed as 50 48 46 48 44 46 etc...
Why are my counter values incrementing and decrementing?

```
 mCounterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CounterView);
    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(50000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String val2 = String.format("%f", (float) millisUntilFinished);
            mCounterText.setText(val2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mCounterText.setText("done");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: If timer should fire every 1000 milliseconds, why are values decreasing by 2 milliseconds between calls. Also, why cast `long` to `float` and display using `%f`? Just convert to string using `Long.toString(millisUntilFinished)`.

Comment: Also, the values that would be printed form the above code that you posted would be in milliseconds, it wont be in seconds. So it wont print 50, 48, instead it would output 50000, 49000.

Comment: I guess there are some glitches in converting to `float` (why do you?).

Comment: Well, above code is not exact code I was using, I was trying to debug and find out whats gone wrong, hence code got changed. When I did clean project and make project, it worked well for few times and again giving same problem.

Comment: Well, above code is not exact code I was using, I was trying to debug and find out whats gone wrong, hence code got changed. When I did clean project and make project, it worked well for few times and again giving same problem. CountDownTimer countDownTimer= new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mCounterText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mCounterText.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();